# Writing a stored function to return an array of rowid

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a stored function to return an array of `rowid`. The first thing I do is to create the `TABLE` type for `rowid` by:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_ROWID_ARRAY IS TABLE OF ROWID;
```

However, the following error message is shown:

```
PLS-00531: Unsupported type in a VARRAY or TABLE type: 'ROWID'.
```

After some googling, it looks like that Oracle 11gR2 does not allow to create a `table` type of `rowid`.

So is there any workaround so that I can write a stored function to return multiple rowid(s)?

I hope to simplify my SQL by writing like below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM GET_ROW_IDS('A', 'B', 'C'));
```

Comment: ROWID is not a valid datatype in Oracle. It's a pseudocolumn which within a database represents the physical location on disk where the record lives. Use a collection of varchar2 type to store rowids

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_ROWID_ARRAY IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

Comment: @PrashantMishra: ROWID is even a datatype, but it can not be used to create a table

Comment: @Aleksej--you are right...I missed it.It's a datatype as well. and we can have it as column too in table :
SQL> create table test(t rowid);
Table created
Executed in 0.613 seconds

and it accepts only rowids:
SQL> insert into test values('AAAAB0AABAAAAOhAAA');
1 row inserted
Executed in 0.578 seconds

SQL> insert into test values('123');
insert into test values('123')
ORA-01410: invalid ROWID

Comment: @PrashantMishra: you're right, I was unclear: you can't use it in a table type

Comment: I am not totally clear of the requirement. You are using GET_ROW_IDS to get the rowids of 'A', 'B', 'C'. Then you are using that rowid to fetch from TABLE_A. So evidently GET_ROW_IDS is getting the rows from TABLE_A only. again the rowid is being used to query same table. This is evidently not your exact requirement. Could you please tell us your exact requirement ?

Comment: 'A', 'B' and 'C' are just some parameters for the stored function, not the row values in TABLE_A.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be converting the rowid into varchar, return a table of varchar2 and then convert them back to rowid type. 
For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v varchar2(100);
  3      n number;
  4  begin
  5      select ROWIDTOCHAR(rowid)
  6      into v
  7      from dual;
  8      --
  9      dbms_output.put_line('ROWID varchar: ' || v);
 10      --
 11      select count(1)
 12      into n
 13      from dual
 14      where rowid = CHARTOROWID(V);
 15      --
 16      dbms_output.put_line('Found rows: ' || n);
 17  end;
 18  /
ROWID varchar: AAAAB0AABAAAAOhAAB
Found rows: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need a standalone SQL array type for this? If you keep things purely within PL/SQL it should be fine (tested in 11.2.0.4):

```
declare 
   type rowidtable is table of rowid;
   t rowidtable;
begin
   select rowid bulk collect into t from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line('t(1) contains ' || t(1));
end;
/

t(1) contains AAAAB0AABAAAAEbAAA

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```